# How do you add NA values for timestamps that weren't logged in? Automating payroll and generating payslips

Tags: python, pandas

I have the timestamp data of employees however the machine only records timestamps and doesn't make a difference between morning time in, morning time out, afternoon time in, afternoon time out. This makes it difficult to write succeeding codes to calculate pay. There are a lot of edge cases here:

1. Worker doesn't come in or worker only comes in in the afternoon
2. Worker does overtime so he only logs his morning time in and afternoon time out (sometimes reaching the second day since he comes back after midnight).

A regular employee's timestamp data would look like this:
[regular worker's timestamp data with 4 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr6MT.png)

But an irregular worker's timestamp data would look like this: [irregular worker's timestamp data with 3 columns (sometimes only 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK19n.png)

What's a good way to ensure that there are 4 columns (for timestamps) for each employee and for each date?

My code below:

```
file = pd.read_excel('AGL_001.xlsx') #file of timestamps
file = file[file['Name GMNo'] != 'SaM 1'] #got rid of useless items
file = file.drop(columns = ['No', 'TMNo','EnNo','Mode']).reset_index(drop = True) #got rid of useless items
file.rename(columns = {'Name GMNo':'employee','DateTime':'datetime'}, inplace = True)
file['week']= file['datetime'].dt.week
weekday_change = {0:1,1:2,2:3,3:4,4:5,5:6,6:7} #Monday as 1 Saturday as 6
file['day'] = file['datetime'].dt.weekday.map(weekday_change)
file['date'] = file['datetime'].dt.date
file['time'] = file['datetime'].dt.time
file = file.sort_values(['date','employee']).reset_index(drop = True)
print(file.head())
```

[Output of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJobR.png)

If we get the timestamp data of an irregular worker named Mark at Week 39:

```
mark = file[(file.week == 39) & (file.employee == 'MARK')]
mark = mark[['datetime','day']].pivot(columns = 'day', values = 'datetime').reset_index(drop = True).rename_axis(None)
mark = mark.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().values)).T
```

[Output of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsSbD.png)

As you can see here, the worker doesn't come in on Monday and only has two timestamps for most of the week.

**How can I input NA values for each day and for each time interval (morning time out, afternoon time in) so that each employee gets exactly 4 timestamps (including NAs) each day?**

Hope my case was explained well enough! Please don't hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Well sort the timestamps by day, invalidate any uneven counts per day, count up the intervals of the even pairs and you have their total hours, right, or am I missing something?

Comment: And, hi! Welcome to StackOverflow ;) You did a great job at building your case, but I'd say on StackOverflow we're usually looking for more specific questions that are applicable to many developers.

Comment: Oh I see! Hehe sorry I'll try to make the questions more specific :) Thank you so much!